# How to configure virtual host to consider domain path in Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

the following virtual host definition is working for an arbitrary url starting with "http://1.2.3.4:80/*"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /home/user/www/application/current/public
     <Directory /home/user/www/application/current/public>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How to rewrite this configuration so that it is applied only for url's starting with "http://1.2.3.4:80/user/*"

I tried "ServerPath /user", but it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Webserver configuration questions are a better fit for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), however, this question deals with very basic `mod_rewrite` rules so [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask) would be the best place to start. Closing as off topic - please see our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) or inquire at [Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions regarding action taken.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ServerPath` is a legacy directive that is used to support HTTP/1.0 clients which don't support the `Host:` header. Therefore, an alternative is to have the primary vhost [serve up a page with links using URL prefixes that Apache can use for routing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/examples.html#serverpath).

For this legacy support mechanism to work, you need to disregard the `Host` header completely (since the browsers you need to support would not send one). So you can't use `ServerName` and `ServerPath` simultaneously.

I'd just use `mod_rewrite` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say I can't answer your question directly but I am fascinated by it. I've been doing Apache support on various fora for 6 years and this is the first time I've seen a ServerPath question. What made you consider it?

It's such an old and disused feature that I suspect even ServerPath forgot ServerPath existed.